# Connect multiple devices with wi-fi in the forest

Tags: android, networking, wifi, android-wifi

I would like to make a game which takes place in the forest (around 2 hectares). The players(around 30) must have their phone connected to a router via wi-fi so that every players are connected to each others via LAN.

But I don't know how to make this possible. 
Wifi mesh routers ? Helium baloon that spread wifi above the forest ?

Comment: Checkout the google connections API. https://developers.google.com/nearby/connections/overview

I dont know how feasible it will be if it is a dense forest but I think that is something of what you are looking for

Answer (score 2):

Using **Network Service Discovery** you can achieve this. You need a wifi router to connect all the devices. One device will be a host and others will be a client.

Go through this link https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/nsd.html

Answer (score 1):

The question is kind of broad, but here are my attempts at possible solutions

1. Have you thought about using wifi-direct between the devices? One possible implementation of this is to have a central router, some older phones/devices spread out in the forest connected to the router and eachother through wifi-direct. Then the players running around will be covered

"Wi-Fi Direct, initially called Wi-Fi P2P, is a Wi-Fi standard enabling devices to easily connect with each other without requiring a wireless access point.[1] Wi-Fi Direct allows two devices to establish a direct Wi-Fi connection without requiring a wireless router. "

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wi-Fi_Direct

2. If data is not an issue, and service is okay, probably better to connect them to a cloud through their regular data connections.